# Django UserManager create_user failing with 'NoneType' object not callable

Tags: python, django, authentication, model

I followed the code in this custom Django user model [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) almost verbatim, and when I try to create a user it fails on the last parameter of `self.model` with the error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The relevant code snippet is below:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, email, password=None, 
                first_name=None, 
                last_name=None
               ):
    now = timezone.now()
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)

    user = self.model(email=email, 
                        first_name=first_name, 
                        last_name=last_name
                      )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=False)
last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=False)

objects = MyUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')

def get_full_name(self):
    """
    Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
    """
    full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    return full_name.strip()
```

It looks like `self.model` is `None`, but I thought having the line `objects = MyUserManager()` in `MyUser` is what associated the two.

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api/tests/test_location.py", line 24, in setUp
    first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
  File "api/models.py", line 99, in create_user
    last_name=last_name
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I call it like so:

```
MyUserManager().create_user(email=email, password=password, first_name=first_name, 
            last_name=last_name)
```

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback.

Comment: added the full traceback

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There will be no model instance attached to that instance of `MyUserManager` if you instantiate it directly and call the `create_user` method like so. You should instead make the call from your `MyUser` model:

```
my_user = MyUser.objects.create_user(email=email, 
                                     password=password, 
                                     first_name=first_name, 
                                     last_name=last_name)
```

Comment: But then how can you create a user via the UserManager? Or is that not the django convention? If not then what is the UserManager for?

Comment: @cph2117 `MyUser.objects` is an instance of the manager (See `objects = MyUserManager()`)

Comment: Ohhh okay I misunderstood the paradigm. Thanks